# Custom set reminders

Tags: ipad

I have to change my pain relief patch every 3 days so I have set up a reminder on my phone. It alerted me today but still says overdue.  How do I keep it on to remind me without having to delete it and put the next due date in?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which iPhone model and iOS? You have the question tagged with iPad, do you need the reminder on both?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've already set it to repeat every 3 days, you can do any of the following:

- within the Reminders app, tap the radio button next to the reminder to mark it as completed
- if you have an alert that appears on the Lock screen, swipe left and select *Mark as Completed*
- if you have a device that supports 3D Touch (e.g. an iPhone 6s and above, but not presently any iPad models), you can also hard press and select *Mark as Completed*

Regardless of the option above, the reminder will repeat as per the schedule you've set.